# Exception disappears if I stop at a breakpoint

Tags: python

**Python 3.6.2**

The problem with the code below is that being run, it raises an exception.
But being stepped in debugger, it works perfectly. Where I stop in the debugger is marked as breakpoint in the comments.

I tried the command both in IDE and in the shell. Exception raises. So, this problem is not related to the IDE.

This situation shook me a bit. 
I made a video of it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUcMpEzooDk

**Could you give me a kick here? How can it be?**

Comment on the code below (not related to the problem, but just for the most curious).

This is an utility to use with Django web framework.
Users upload files, they are put to the media directory.

Of course, Django knows where the media directory is sutuated.
And then Django keeps in the database paths relative to media. Something like this:

- it_1/705fad82-2f68-4f3c-90c2-116da3ad9a40.txt'
- e5474da0-0fd3-4fa4-a85f-15c767ac32d4.djvu

I want to know exactly that files kept in media correspond to paths in the database. No extra files, no shortage.

**Code:**

```
from pathlib import Path

class <Something>():
    def _reveal_lack_extra_files(self):

        path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, '../media/')

        image_files = Image.objects.values_list("file", flat=True)
        image_files = [Path(os.path.join(path, file)) for file in image_files]

        item_files = ItemFile.objects.values_list("file", flat=True)
        item_files = [Path(os.path.join(path, file)) for file in item_files]

        sheet_files = SheetFile.objects.values_list("file", flat=True)
        sheet_files = [Path(os.path.join(path, file)) for file in sheet_files]

        expected_files = set().union(image_files, item_files, sheet_files)

        real_files = set()

        glob_generator = list(Path(path).glob("**/*"))

        for posix_path in glob_generator:
            if os.path.isfile(posix_path._str): # Breakpoint
                real_files.add(posix_path)


        lack = expected_files.difference(real_files)
        extra = real_files.difference(expected_files)

        assert bool(lack) == False, "Lack of files: {}".format(lack)
        assert bool(extra) == False, "Extra files: {}".format(extra)
```

**Traceback:**

```
/home/michael/PycharmProjects/venv/photoarchive_4/bin/python /home/michael/Documents/pycharm-community-2017.1.5/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 43849 --file /home/michael/PycharmProjects/photoarchive_4/manage.py checkfiles
warning: Debugger speedups using cython not found. Run '"/home/michael/PycharmProjects/venv/photoarchive_4/bin/python" "/home/michael/Documents/pycharm-community-2017.1.5/helpers/pydev/setup_cython.py" build_ext --inplace' to build.
pydev debugger: process 3840 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 171.4694.67)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michael/Documents/pycharm-community-2017.1.5/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1591, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/home/michael/Documents/pycharm-community-2017.1.5/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1018, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/home/michael/Documents/pycharm-community-2017.1.5/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/photoarchive_4/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/venv/photoarchive_4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/venv/photoarchive_4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/venv/photoarchive_4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/venv/photoarchive_4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/photoarchive_4/general/management/commands/checkfiles.py", line 59, in handle
    self._reveal_lack_extra_files()
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/photoarchive_4/general/management/commands/checkfiles.py", line 39, in _reveal_lack_extra_files
    if os.path.isfile(posix_path._str):
AttributeError: _str

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Where is the `Path` class coming from?

Comment: Patrick, it is from pathlib import Path. I have now added it to the question.

Comment: It looks like you're running Python 3.6, so `isfile` should accept a path-like object.  Try `if os.path.isfile(posix_path)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `_str` attribute on paths, which is undocumented and not guaranteed to be set. In general, an underscore prefix indicates that this is a private attribute that should not be used by user code. If you want to convert a path to a string, just use `str(the_path)` instead.

But in this case, you don't need to do so: `Path` objects have an [`is_file`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.is_file) method which you can call instead. Another possibility is to pass the `Path` object itself to the [`os.path.isfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) function, which is supported on Python 3.6.

Comment: Thank you very much. Perfect explanation.